# Import two files

Tags: javascript, npm, import, gulp, gulp-sass

Recently started learning imports and faced the following problem
**After installing the package in `gulpfile`, you need to make the following entry:**

```
const sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));
```

Can I somehow make this record using import?
**The only thing that comes to my mind is:**

```
import gulp_sass from 'gulp-sass';
import sass from 'sass';
```

But there one variable is assigned two values, and here, in fact, there are 2 "variables" and it turns out somehow not very good because you need to use one name in the task, not two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would import from 'sass' with a different name, and construct `sass` per function call, just like when using `require`.

```
import gulp_sass from 'gulp-sass';
import _sass_ from 'sass';

const sass = gulp_sass(_sass_);
```

Comment: It worked, thanks!